# Is it possible to include javascript in view rendered with ajax in asp mvc 4?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm having serious trouble trying to include javascript in a Partial View with asp mvc 4, reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491801/how-does-mvc4-optimization-allow-partial-view-scripts) I followed the instructions to create a custom Html helper to include the js. Unfortunately, either I call it from the layout, and then the method to actually include the Javascript is never called on time (meaning that the page request has already been called when I do the ajax request) or I try to include it in my Partial View, but partial views seem to automatically strip down any javascript written in them. So I tried to render a standard View, but even that hasn't solved the problem. The thing is then, is it even possible to render javascript in a view called with ajax in asp mvc? Has someone done it, please advice. I actually need to run javascript inside my "ajax called" view because I have to detect the values inside a form that is inside that view. I won't post the code of the Helper because it's entirely from the post referenced. 
Thanks!

Ok I'll try to be more specific as why I think I need the javascript in my particular view. The following is the code of the main view:

```
    @model MvcCursosSSP.Models.CursosModel
@using System.Threading;
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "AgregarHorario";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    int numhoras = ViewBag.NumeroHoras;
    int dias = ViewBag.Dias;
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
}

<h2>AgregarHorario</h2>
<table class="horario">
    <colgroup>
        <col id="col1">
        <col id="col2">
        <col id="col3">
        <col id="col4">
        <col id="col5">
        <col id="col6">
    </colgroup>
    <caption>@if (ViewBag.Modulo != null)
             {
                 <text>Modulo </text>@ViewBag.Modulo[0].NumModulo.ToString()<br />@ViewBag.Modulo[0].Nombre.ToString()<br />
             }Horario del @Model.FechaInicio.Day.ToString() de @Model.FechaInicio.ToString("MMMM", culture) al @Model.FechaTermino.Day.ToString() de @Model.FechaTermino.ToString("MMMM", culture)</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Horario</th>
        @for (int i = 0; i <= @dias; i++)
        {
            <th>@Model.FechaInicio.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd", culture)&nbsp;@Model.FechaInicio.AddDays(i).Day.ToString()</th>
        }
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i <= @numhoras; i++)
            {
                var newTime = @Model.HorarioInicio.Add(new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0));
                <tr><td>@newTime.Hours:00</td>@for (int j = 0; j <= @dias; j++)
                                                 {
                                                 <td id="@newTime.Hours" rel="@Model.FechaInicio.AddDays(j).Day.ToString()"><span class="addHorario">AgregarHorario</span></td>
                                                 }
                </tr>
            } 
        </tbody>
    </thead>
    </table>
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('span.addHorario').click(function () {
        var td = $(this).parent('td');
        td.load("/Cursos/CreateMateria/" + new Date(@Model.FechaInicio.Year.ToString(), @Model.FechaInicio.Month.ToString(), td.attr('rel')).toISOString().substring(0,10) + '/' + td.attr('id'));
    });
    $('button[id^="save"]').click(function () {
        horaini = $('#horarioInicio'+$(this).attr('id').substring(4, $(this).attr('id').length)).val();
        horafin = $('#horarioFin'+$(this).attr('id').substring(4, $(this).attr('id').length)).val();
        alert(parseInt(horafin)-parseInt(horaini));
    });
</script>
}
```

But the final javascript starting with the line: `$('button[id^="save"]').click` is not working, I think because the dom has already been built and jquery isn't recognizing anything. Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Scripts should in the main view or layout, not in a partial view, but why do you think you need a html helper for this?

Comment: Sorry read the following comment, I tried to edit this one but I finally posted another one. The thing I wonder is how to run the javascript when the dom has already changed due to the ajax call?

Comment: I have setup a fiddle to illustrate this [link]http://jsfiddle.net/t97Lue3m/2/ I think I need the javascript to run in my partial view for it to run correctly, otherwise the call to document.ready already had past. Am I wrong?

Comment: If your main view has an ajax function to dynamically load a partial view, then you use event delegation, e.g. `$(document).on('click', '#someElement', function() { // do something });` Ideally, replace `document` with the closest ancestor which exists at the time you first render the view, and `#someElement` could be `.someClassName` in your case (rather than `'button[id^="save"]'`)

Comment: Sorry it seems like you were thinking the same thing as I was posting my answer. Nobody stole anyone's idea though. I did as you said. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it. I looks like Jquery already has the solution to this, simply by adding a callback function to the load like so:

```
$('span.addHorario').click(function () {
    var td = $(this).parent('td');
    td.load("/Cursos/CreateMateria/" + new Date(@Model.FechaInicio.Year.ToString(), @Model.FechaInicio.Month.ToString(), td.attr('rel')).toISOString().substring(0,10) + '/' + td.attr('id'), function(){
        $('button[id^="save"]').click(function () {
            horaini = $('#horarioInicio'+$(this).attr('id').substring(4, $(this).attr('id').length)).val();
            horafin = $('#horarioFin'+$(this).attr('id').substring(4, $(this).attr('id').length)).val();
            alert(parseInt(horafin)-parseInt(horaini));
        });   
    });
});
```

and now I can manipulate the dom of my partial view. 
Thanks!